# Python does not work after installing fastai and boto3. Permission denied // Python was not found

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, hyperlink, permissions

Last thing I did was pip install boto3 and fastai through git bash yesterday. I can't imagine if anything else could have had any influence.

I have been using python for a few months now, but today it stopped running. I opened my
Sublime Text - and after running some simple code I got:
"Python was not found but can be installed from the Microsoft Store".

GIT bash:

> $ python --version bash:
>   /c/Users/.../AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python: Permission
>   denied

But if I open up a file of python 3 in this link:

> C:\Users...\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start
>   Menu\Programs\Python 3.7

My Python works.

I think I have to redirect my main python file from the first link directory to the second and have no clue how to do this, that my Git and Sublime would be able to pick on this.

Comment: Can you do an `ls -l $(which python)` in Git Bash and let us know the result?

Comment: After Windows Appstore install:
-rwxr-xr-x 1 Karolina 197121 97296 Mar 25  2019 /c/Users/Karolina/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37-32/python*

Yesterday I tried that as well, the start was identical, although I can't really remember the link, if it was the same.

Answer (score 0):

So, I gave up and just installed the recommended link from Microsoft store. So now I possibly have 4 pythons with 2 different versions in 3 locations, but hey.... it works :)

Regarding a comment below my first questions:
When I run $ ls -l `which python` in GITbash, it gives:

-rwxr-xr-x 1 ... 197121 97296 Mar 25  2019 /c/Users/.../AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37-32/python*

- /.../ is just my user name

Yesterday I tried that as well, the start was identical, although I can't really remember the link, if it was the same.